# How can I see if a column exist ? before instanciate resultset object?

Tags: java, database, database-schema

I have a program in java that will execute a query which comes from a file.

In the file I have queries like:

```
select f1, f2, f3 from tbl1
select f1, f2, f3 from tbl2
```

These queries will be executed dynamically in the process, but when some field does not exist in the table, it show me the following error:

```
column "f1" does not exist.
```

I want to handle these errors. 
Is there a way to know if a column exists on the table before running the query?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the `DatabaseMetaData` to give you information about [columns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Connection con = ...
DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
boolean tbl1_f1_exists = md.getColumns(null, null, "tbl1", "f1").next();
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you for your answer... 

but how to know the name of the field ??? 

f1 ... I don't know the name ... 

is there a way to get it ?

Comment: @EasyTI you would need to parse the query string to extract field and table names. That's not an easy task...

Comment: in the SQLEXception appears a message that says:

"Collum 'f1' no found" .. 

do you know if there is a way to get the name of the field ? because if i get the name of the field in here i think i can solve my problem

Comment: use `e.getMessage()` and then extract the substring between the two quote chars

Comment: ir there other way ??? Generic to all databases..... in sql server it comes with simple quote (') but in oracle comer (")......

Comment: @EasyTI so then be prepared for both cases.